# Why is my spy test failing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, ecmascript-6, angular-promise

I have the following test:

```
beforeEach(inject(($document, _DirectiveReadyService_) => {
  DirectiveReadyService = _DirectiveReadyService_;
  foo = jasmine.createSpy('foo');
}));

it('should resolve `foo` subscriber when `foo` is published', () => {
  DirectiveReadyService.subscribe('foo').then(foo);
  DirectiveReadyService.publish('foo');

  expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

And my DirectiveReadyService looks like:

```
export class DirectiveReadyService {
  constructor($q, $rootScope) {
    'ngInject';

    this._$q = $q;
    this._directives = {};

    const resetDirectives = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', () => {
      this._directives = {};
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$destroy', resetDirectives);
  }

  publish(type, ...params) {
    if (this._directives[type]) {
      console.log('publish', type);
      this._directives[type].resolve(params);
    }
  }

  subscribe(...types) {
    const done = [];

    console.log('subscribe', types);

    types.forEach(type => {
      this._directives[type] = this._directives[type] || this._$q.defer();
      done.push(this._directives[type].promise);
    });

    return this._$q.all(done).then(result => {
      console.log('done', result);
      return result;
    });
  }
}
```

When I run the tests, I see the following in the console:

```
'subscribe', ['foo']
'publish', 'foo'
```

But I never get the `'done'` and my test fails. However, developing against this service and previewing in the browser console logs all the way through to `'done'` so I know the service works. What am I doing wrong in the unit test?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... My test was missing `$rootScope.$apply();`. With this, the promise resolves.

```
beforeEach(inject(($document, _$rootScope_, _DirectiveReadyService_) => {
  DirectiveReadyService = _DirectiveReadyService_;
  foo = jasmine.createSpy('foo');
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
}));

it('should resolve `foo` subscriber when `foo` is published', () => {
  DirectiveReadyService.subscribe('foo').then(foo);
  DirectiveReadyService.publish('foo');

  $rootScope.apply();

  expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```